# I get an error when trying to do TexInfo PDF output

Tags: texinfo

https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html#Short-Sample-Texinfo-File

In the sample code of the above URL, using TexInfo, I am trying to output PDF, but the following error occurs.

```sh
$ makeinfo --pdf sample.texinfo
sample.texinfo:28: @menu seen before first @node
sample.texinfo:28: perhaps your @top node should be wrapped in @ifnottex rather than @ifinfo?
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem, and found [an email about this issue](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-texinfo/2015-03/msg00009.html) which explains mainly that either you can put the `@menu` *within* the `@ifnottex` block (which I find strange that the official sample docs wouldn't), or you can run `texi2pdf` on the file directly by writing

```
texi2pdf <FILE>
```

which works perfectly for me, so I suppose it goes through less validation. Although again it's strange since `makeinfo --pdf` is supposed to just be a wrapper for `texi2pdf` from what I understand. `texi2dvi --pdf` works also.